# InputSimulator does not simulate mouse clicks

Tags: c#, winforms, input, click, mouse

I am using InputSimulator to simulate key presses and mouse clicks. Every key I've tested so far works, except the mouse buttons. I send them like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //In this example I am trying to simulate the left mouse button
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); 
        InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.LBUTTON);
    }
```

But nothing happens. Do I do anything wrong?

Library: [InputSimulator](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Seems to be a known issue (maybe) [LButton simulation is not working](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/workitem/13006)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know much about `InputStimulator` but according to [this post](http://www.jarloo.com/simulating-mouse-clicks-in-c/). You can stimulate mouse click using;

```
      [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
      public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData,  int dwExtraInfo);

      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080;
      private const int MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100;

      //.................................
      //In your own function:

      int X = 1220;
      int Y = 13;
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, X, Y, 0, 0);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
```

Remember to add `using System.Runtime.InteropService;`

Comment: what about scrolling; can you give me an example of scrolling horizantally and vertically?

Answer (score 7):

The latest version of InputSimulator supports mouse events. Here is how to use it:

```
var sim = new InputSimulator();
sim.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
```

Note that binary download is outdated, so you have to build the library from sources.

Comment: where can I find the latest version?

Comment: Get the source code here: https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: It's difficult to tell with this project as the current NuGet package  "Windows Input Simulator" is version 1.0.4.0 and was published on 12-Dec-2013. The latest source code has an assembly version of 0.2.0.0 (not a typo!) and dates from the same day (12-Dec-2013). Hmm.

Comment: Actually version 0.2.0.0 is also in NuGet under the name "WindowsInput" and released on the 27-Nov-2013. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would guess that "Windows Input Simulator" is actually up to date, but "WindowsInput" is a version behind (the dev Michael Noonan must have jumped from 0.2.0.0 to 1.0.4.0, but I'm not sure).

Comment: The confusion doesn't end there. There is also InputSimulatorPlus by the same guy. While the examples on Github suggest that the main object is called statically ie InputSimulator.DoStuff(), the actual NuGet package class expects to be instantiated.